# countModules in module chrome function

Tags: module, template-override, layout

I'm using grid layout and I need to calculate column width depending on amount of active modules in a position. I'm assigning the css class within my module chrome.

What I was doing till now was something like this:

```
$position1ColumnWidth = functionThatCalculatesWidth('position1');
...
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="customChrome" colWidth="<?php echo $position1ColumnWidth?>"/>
```

And than in `modules.php` I'd do something like this:

```
function modChrome_customChrome ($module, &$params, &$attribs) {
    echo "<div class=\"" . $attribs["colWidth"] . ">";
    echo $module->content;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

This way seems dirty to me because I have to calculate column width in my index php and it adds unnecessary code if I'd like to add a new position.

Is there a way to access countModules function for position that is currently rendered from within module chrome to separate logic from template as much as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chrome function like this could work:

```
function modChrome_mymod($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{   
    jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
    $class = "";
    if(count(JModuleHelper::getModules('position'))) {
        $total_modules = count(JModuleHelper::getModules('position'));
        $width = round(100 / $total_modules);
        $class = " width-".$width;
    }
    if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
        <div class="gridmod<?php echo $class; ?> floatleft moduletable<?php echo htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')); ?>">
    // Rest of your chrome function goes here ...
}
```

It counts the total modules of the given position, then divide 100/ number of modules and assign this to a class name.

You can then create styles for these expected class names like:

```
.width-100 {width:100%;}  
.width-50 {width:50%;}  
.width-33 {width:33%;}  
.width-25 {width:25%;}
```

and so on.